# Error: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, fetch-api, google-maps-timezone

I'm using fetch to call [Google TimeZone](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/overview#maps_http_timezone-js). But I'm getting an error when trying to pass the lat/lng and timestamp in as body paramters.

> Error: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body

Here is my code.
Does Google allow it to be called this way?

```js
const data = new FormData();
data.append('location', this.latitude.value + ',' + this.longitude.value);
data.append('timestamp', Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000).toString());
data.append('key', 'my google API key')
const timeZoneResult = await fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {},
  body: data,
});
const timeZone = await timeZoneResult.json();
```

This way, all in the url string, works fine!

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810%2C-119.6822510&timestamp=1331161200&key=myKeyHere

Comment: a GET request cannot have a body, as the error clearly indicates. A GET is a pure URL-based operation.

Comment: is there a way to construct this in parts so I can keep the lat/lng, timestamp and key seperate? Do I just concatenate the string in parts? Is that the only way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error says where the problem is. Method GET cannot have a body. Place the data as a query string.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=...&timestamp=...
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the http specification does not prohibit GET requests from having a body - it is perfectly legal to do so.
However, as MDN points out:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET: 
'Note: Sending body/payload in a GET request may cause some existing implementations to reject the request — while not prohibited by the specification, the semantics are undefined. It is better to just avoid sending payloads in GET requests.'